# Writing lyrics of songs/poems: end in rhyme or complete phrases?

Tags: lyrics

I was wondering if someone could help me figure out readers' preferences when writing down versions of lyrics/verses as I seem to have lost judgement somewhat.

> 1A) Hey Jude, don't make it bad
>   Take a sad song and make it better
>   Remember to let her into your heart
>   Then you can start to make it better
>
> 1B)Hey Jude,
>   don't make it bad
>   take a sad
>   song and make it better
>   remember to let her
>   into your heart
>   then you can start
>   to make it better
>
> 2A)There was a writer loved by folks
>   who liked to sit and read his jokes
>   he'd play word games
>   and think up names of books
>   which amused all these folks
>
> 2B)There was a writer loved by folks
>   who liked to sit and read his jokes
>   he'd play word games
>   and think up names
>   of books which amused all these folks

*by the way, does removing the rhyme make any difference to you? e.g.

> 3A)he'd play word games
>   and think up lines of books
>   which amused all these folks
>
> 3B)he'd play word games
>   and think up lines
>   of books which amused all these folks

If anyone could offer opinions as to which one is more appealing/legible/less disruptive, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Writing down songs is often a little ambiguous; their natural state of being is not written down but sung.

If you wanted to break Hey Jude into more lines, you could do it like this:

> Hey Jude,
>
> don't make it bad,
>
> take a sad song
>
> and make it better;
>
> remember
>
> to let her into your heart,
>
> then you can start
>
> to make it better.

None of those breaks is random! They only follow a somewhat finer structure of the melody than the four-line version. You probably won't want to do this (imagine the chunk of the page it would take in the songbook) but in principle you could. Perhaps if you wanted to make it easier for the singers to keep track.

In contrast,

> take a sad
>
> song and make it better

or

> remember to let her
>
> into your heart

...is just wrong. And would deeply confuse anyone not familiar with the song trying to sing along from the written lyrics. Because it goes *contrary* to the melody.

*Always follow the rhythm.*

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the metrical and rhythmic structure of the song. You should follow the musical phrases, which often match the phrase structure in English (but not always).  In many songs there is rhyme at the end of a line, but some songs don't rhyme, and sometimes the rhyme is in the [middle of line.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_rhyme)

Hey Jude is usually written as:

> Hey Jude, don't make it bad
>   Take a sad song and make it better
>   Remember to let her into your heart
>   Then you can start to make it better

If, however, an author has indicated that they want the lines split differently, then follow the author's wishes.  In a limerick, the metric structure is very fixed It is based on the "anapest" a metric structure of three syllables. The limerick has three anapests in the first two lines, then two in lines 3 and 4.  The line break often happens in the middle of a phrase of English. Limericks also have rhyme, but that is not the reason for the line break:

> There was a writer loved by folks
>   who liked to sit and read his jokes
>   he'd play word games
>   and think up names
>   of books which amused all these folks

The rhyme is essential to the limerick. If you remove the rhyme, you're breaking the rules of game (which can be done for comic reasons)

> There once was a limerick by me
>   That didn't rhyme at all
>   It didn't have the two little middle lines
>   that are much shorter than the others
>   But worst of all, this limerick by me
>   had one line too many.

Comment: The bad limerick is an old joke from Griff Rhys Jones.

Comment: Your definition of a limerick is fine but "There was a writer" isn't a limerick. It is iambic, until line 5 which goes wonky and uses anapests.

Comment: True, but I think it is meant to follow a similar pattern to limericks

Comment: Yes, perhaps you're right. I was always feel a bit let down by limericks where the last word of the 5th line is the same as that of the 1st or 2nd line. But even Lear wrote those sometimes.